# Insert Excel Formulas in VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am exporting an excel file and looking to insert multiple Excel Formulas into different Excel sheets.
The excel formulas are not all the same for each sheet. Most functions however involve =MID().
All sheets are in the same excel workbook.
Each sheet has a unique set of formulas.
The code I have so far is shown below.
Any help is appreciated.

```
    Protected Sub Export_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Export.Click
    Dim constr As String = GlbSQLCon
    Dim query As String = "SELECT Title FROM Test;"
    query &= "SELECT Subtitle FROM Test;"
    query &= "SELECT Body FROM Test;"
    query &= "SELECT Research FROM Test"

    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using ds As New DataSet()
                    sda.Fill(ds)
                    ds.Tables(0).TableName = "sheet1"
                    ds.Tables(1).TableName = "sheet2"
                    ds.Tables(2).TableName = "sheet3"
                    ds.Tables(3).TableName = "sheet4"

                    Using wb As New XLWorkbook()
                        For Each dt As DataTable In ds.Tables
                            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt)

                            '--Excel Formula (sheet1)
                            '=LEFT(A2,3),=MID(A2,4,8)

                            '--Excel Formula (sheet2)
                            '=LEFT(A2,3),=MID(A2,4,7)

                            '--Excel Formula (sheet3)
                            '=LEFT(A2,5)

                            '--Excel Formula (sheet4)
                            '=MID(A2,27,6),=MID(A2,33,4),=MID(A2,37,2)

                            wb.Save()
                        Next

                        Response.Clear()
                        Response.Buffer = True
                        Response.Charset = ""
                        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=text.xlsx" &Filename)
                        Using MyMemoryStream As New MemoryStream()
                            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream)
                            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
                            Response.Flush()
                            Response.End()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry but to me at least this all seems a little off, and I'm struggling to understand exactly what you're attempting to do here.  All the Response stuff at the bottom that comes out of nowhere has me really confused and seems to serve zero purpose.  Anyway, you're adding new empty worksheets for each of your ds.Tables. Is the data for that supposed to be coming from the data table objects?  Are you asking how to append that data in your workbook?  Do you actually require the formula inserted, or the resultant data after the formula is applied?

Comment: Hi, sorry to clarify I am exporting an excel file and I want to insert formulas so that when I open it from the export the formula is in the excel file